# Can we configure i2c low and high period rather than having it at 50% duty cycle?

Tags: embedded, i2c

I want to run i2c commands at 400khz which means 2.5usec per cycle.

ex. considering engine will supply clock at 50% duty cycle which means 1.25usec low and 1.25usec high.

but according to I2c specification minimum clock low time should be 1.3usec at fastmode(400khz) which violates the rule of i2c standard when we operate at 400khz with 50% duty cycle.

so my question is can we have configurable duty cycle in i2c engine where we configure low time 60% and high time 40% which will meet the i2c spec?

your answers are appreciated...

Thank you:)

Comment: belongs to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: there is no reason why it has to be 50% duty cycle, but you do need to look at the data sheet for the target device and insure that each half of your clock meets their spec.  shorten that and they dont guarantee their part will respond.